# Computer wont boot into bios

Tags: boot, bios

I have been having this issue recently where my computer won't boot into bios or anything, it never gives video signal to my monitor and my keyboard does not light up. I've tried clearing CMOS which worked for about a week until it started happening again, I've also replaced the CMOS battery. I have taken on of my ram sticks out, taken my graphics card out and also cleaned the PC.

System Specs:
`CPU: AMD-Ryzen 5 3600`
`GPU: Asus Tuf Geforce GTX 1650 OC Edition`
`MB: Asrock B550M Steel Legend`
`RAM: 2x Crucial Ballistix 8gb`
`PSU: Not sure, But it is a name brand PSU`

Comment: Do fans spin up? Is there beep codes? When the system has a pre- boot halt it will usually use beep codes or an embedded screen or indicator on the mainboard itself to communicate information regarding the fault causing the halt. Have you tried a different screen and video cables?

Comment: Fans spin up normally, I have tried to use a different screen and different video cables, there are no beep codes but there are red lights that mean something is not working and those red lights are telling me that there is something wrong with the booting of the pc and the gpu.

Comment: Looks like a hardware failure on the motherboard.

Comment: Could possibly be but if it’s my gpu is there a way I could get a replace from asus? The gpu is only 1 year old.